# Spring-boot Initialize a database with more than on file

Tags: spring-boot

I use spring-boot to initialize my (H2) database with several schema.sql files.

Here is the configuration :

```
spring.datasource.initialize=false
spring.datasource.schema=classpath*:db/schema*.sql
```

I see in the doc that if a pattern is used the scripts are executed in lexical order of their URL or filename. Is it possible to change this behaviour?

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for the ordering? I can't find any mention of it in http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: Here is the link : http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch12s09.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's talking about Spring Framework's support for using XML config to initialise a DataSource. You're using Spring Boot without any XML so the ordering doesn't apply. I've opened https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6316 to consider using the same ordering in Spring Boot.

Comment: So what is the order used for spring-boot?

Comment: It's undefined and you shouldn't rely on it being in any particular order. As I said in my answer you should use a single file or Flyway or Liquibase if you need more control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no support for controlling the order in which the scripts are called. The expectation is that you'll have a single schema file for all DB platforms or one schema file per DB platform if you need to do anything that's platform-specific.

If you want more control over the initialisation of your database, the recommended approach is to use Flyway or Liquibase.